# Mapping definition for [location] has unsupported parameters: [geohash : true] : Elasticsearch 5.X

Tags: elasticsearch, geopoints, elasticsearch-5, geohashing

I'm using **elasticsearch 5.2**, but when setting up index mapping with [geohash:true] for a geo_point field I'm getting the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Mapping definition for [location] has unsupported parameters:  [geohash : true]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [jdloc]: Mapping definition for [location] has unsupported parameters:  [geohash : true]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Mapping definition for [location] has unsupported parameters:  [geohash : true]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Can anyone tell me if [**geoshash**] has been depreciated or there is another way to generate and store geohash from geo_point field type while creating documents?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal_geo_point_literal_fields),

> **geo_point fields**
>
> Like Numeric fields the Geo point field now uses the
> new BKD tree structure. Since this structure is fundamentally designed
> for multi-dimension spatial data, the following field parameters are
> no longer needed or supported: geohash, geohash_prefix,
> geohash_precision, lat_lon. Geohashes are still supported from an API
> perspective, and can still be accessed using the .geohash field
> extension, but they are no longer used to index geo point data.

Looks like it is no longer supported/needed. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html). According to the example they use `geohash` with following mapping.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

 PUT my_index/my_type/3
{
  "text": "Geo-point as a geohash",
  "location": "drm3btev3e86" 
}
```

UPDATE:

What I understand from the documentation is that `geohash` is not supported in mapping but you can still access it. So it should be calculated automatically.

Therefore when you index as follows, you should be able to access `geohash` as well.

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "text": "Geo-point as an object",
  "location": { 
    "lat": 41.12,
    "lon": -71.34
  }
}
```

Comment: This is like generating geohash from using another source and storing it elasticsearch explicitly. But I need auto generate geohash from the stored lat lon formated geo_points.